# Exception thrown from try block and try-with-resources Statement

Tags: java, exception

Considering the following code from Java Docs.

```
static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
    try (**BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))**) {
        **return br.readLine();**
    }
}
```

*As per Java docs*,

> In the example readFirstLineFromFile, if exceptions are thrown from
>   both the try block and the try-with-resources statement, then the
>   method readFirstLineFromFile throws the exception thrown from the try
>   block; the exception thrown from the try-with-resources block is
>   suppressed.

On the other hand, it is also mentioned

> Because the BufferedReader instance is declared in a try-with-resource
>   statement, it will be closed regardless of whether the try statement
>   completes normally or abruptly (as a result of the method
>   BufferedReader.readLine throwing an IOException).

(which means that the close method is called only after the try block is executed...as per my understanding)

So, assuming that both try-with-resources statement and try block throw exception and considering the order in which the exceptions are thrown

**1)** exception is first thrown from `try` block `return br.readLine();`

**2)** Then as soon as the try block is completed(irrespective of whether the exception is thrown from the try block), the close method of `Buffered Reader` is called and it then also throws `exception`.

So, ideally the exception thrown from the method `readFirstLineFromFile` should be the one from close method of BufferedReader (since it was executed last) rather than the one from `return br.readLine();` inside try block (as compared to what has been mentioned inside Javadocs)

Can someone please clarify my doubt.

Comment: I don't see why this would be ideal. I'd prefer getting the functional exception thrown by the try block, rather than the technical exception, that I can't do anything about, thrown by the close() method. And if the exception is an IOException because, for example, the file has been deleted, I'd prefer an exception telling me that it's impossible to read from the file, rather than an exception telling me that the reader couldn't be closed (and which is also caused by the file deletion).

Answer (score 0):

you would assume `try(<<stuff>>){stuff.dude();}` is something like `try{stuff.dude();}finally{stuff.close();}`.

So with success or fail, it closes the closable if applicable